# How to use ruby array in sql server query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, sql-server

I am having trouble in passing ruby array in sql query. I am using ruby version 2 and rails 4.0.2.

i have a array which contains project names which is passed by the view page and i am reading it through params in my function in the controller.

This is my function :

```
def fetch_projects()

@projects = params[:projects]

#this is my sql query

@query = " select * from project_view where Projects in '#{@projects.map { |s| s }}'"

@results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(@query)

end
```

I am not able to execute the `@query`.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: Your `@query` seems wrong.

Comment: My two cents: It isn't best practices to use raw sql code  or reference ActiveRecord::Base directly in a controller. It violates MVC and will make your code difficult to maintain by anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid writing raw sql. You are already using a gem called active record that does much more than just running your queries(it keeps it safe to execute & optimizes your queries) and without the hassel of innitiating your connection. You can instead do

```
ProjectView.where(project: @projects)
```

Comment: Using Model helped me at some point , thanks :) . But how do i pass an array of projects in the above code of yours . Other then using .each method is there any other way ?

Comment: Its Rails syntactic sugar that does that for you..if I understood you correctly  the above query is your answer. which would generate a sql query like this 'SELECT * FROM project_view  WHERE project_id IN (1,2)'

Comment: Assuming your @projects is an array of models rails will automatically generate the array of ids to match by

Comment: Hey David Ferd how do i fetch for array of values ? if my @projects contains more then one project name

Comment: from your initial query what is the datatype of the field 'Projects'?

Comment: varchar(50) is the datatype

Answer (score 0):

```
@query = " select * from project_view where Projects in '#{@projects.map { |s| s }}'"
```

I can see two problems here,

1. String interpolation does not work with single quetoes. So use #{} directly in the query string.
2. And your ruby code within string will return Array [1,2,3], so the query fails.

Why don't you try this in Rails way,
For ex: `ProjectView.joins(:projects).where(projects: {id: @projects.pluck(:id)})`

Comment: The whole string is enclosed with double quotes, single quotes are just a part of the normal characters in it.